# Two enum definitions of the same variable

Tags: c, linkage

I've noticed some code in the linux kernel with the following:

In the file [s3c-dma-pl330.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/plat-samsung/include/plat/s3c-dma-pl330.h) there is a definition:

```
enum dma_ch {
...
};
```

and at the end of that file there is: `#include <plat/dma.h>`
In that file ([dma.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/plat-samsung/include/plat/dma.h)) there is: `enum dma_ch;`
No `extern` is written, can you tell what is actually happens?

Does `dma_ch` in dma.h is the same as in s3c-dma-pl330.h? Why isn't there the `extern` specifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum dma_ch;` is a forward declaration of the enumeration.

We use `extern` when we want to refer to an instance of an object that is found in (possibly) some other translation unit. `dma_ch` is not an object, it is a type.

Comment: It is mentioned here http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=450 that forward declaration for enum type should contain its base. Does it?

Comment: That is referring to c++ not c. And this code is allowed because Linux is compiled with C plus some gnu extensions, such as allowing a forward declaration of an enum.